# linear model when all occurrences of independent variables are NA

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, na

I'm looking for suggestions on how to deal with NA's in linear regressions when all occurrences of an independent/explanatory variable are NA (i.e. `x3` below).

I know the obvious solution would be to exclude the independent/explanatory variable in question from the model but I am looping through multiple regions and **would prefer not to have a different functional forms** for each region.

Below is some sample data:

```
set.seed(23409)
n <- 100

time <- seq(1,n, 1)
x1 <- cumsum(runif(n))           
y  <- .8*x1 + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=2)
x2 <- seq(1,n, 1)       
x3 <- rep(NA, n)            
df <- data.frame(y=y, time=time, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3)

# Quick plot of data
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df.melt <-melt(df, id=c("time"))

p <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=time, y=value)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_grid(variable ~ .)
p
```

I have read the documentation for `lm` and tried various `na.action` settings without success:

```
lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df, singular.ok=TRUE)

lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df, na.action=na.omit)
lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df, na.action=na.exclude)

lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df, singular.ok=TRUE, na.exclude=na.omit)
lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df, singular.ok=TRUE, na.exclude=na.exclude)
```

Is there a way to get lm to run without error and simply return a coefficient for the explanatory reflective of the lack of explanatory power (i.e. either zero or NA) from the variable in question?

Comment: An interesting problem, it is interesting to look at the results of `model.matrix(y~x1+x2+x3, df)` -- I think this is where the issue arises. The problem attempting to use `na.action` is that this works on a case by case basis, so if any values of the explanatory variable are NA, the case (row) is omitted.

Comment: Could you just check if the particular variable is all missing using `all(is.na(var))` and then build the formula to pass to `lm` using `paste` and `as.formula`? I.e. - if the variable is all NA, drop it out of the model and maybe save a list of all the formula calls that ended up being used.

Comment: adding to @thelatemail 's comment, you should probably consider removing variables if some proportion (say, half, or a third) of their values are missing. Otherwise, many of your within-group cases will be thrown out (as in listwise deletion) and the coefficients could be seriously biased for the estimation.

Comment: In light of your comments, you will be having a different functional form for regions where data is missing. Having a constant term(i.e. all 0) is different, as this will be aliased with the intercept term, and the result will have `NA` for the coefficient anyway.

Comment: @mnel: agreed, technically the functional form will be different but programmatically it will be the same and more importantly lm won't fail in situations where a certain independent variables are all NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
set.seed(23409)
n <- 100

time <- seq(1,n, 1)
x1 <- cumsum(runif(n))           
y  <- .8*x1 + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=2)
x2 <- seq(1,n, 1)       
x3 <- rep(NA, n)            
df <- data.frame(y=y, time=time, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3)

replaceNA<-function(x){
  if(all(is.na(x))){
    rep(0,length(x)) 
  } else x

} 

lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data= data.frame(lapply(df,replaceNA)))
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data.frame(lapply(df, replaceNA)))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
    0.05467      1.01133     -0.10613           NA  

lm(y~x1+x2, data=df)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
    0.05467      1.01133     -0.10613
```

So you replace the variables which contain only `NA`'s with variable which contains only 0's. you get the coefficient value NA, but all the relevant parts of the model fits are same (expect qr decomposition, but if information about that is needed, it can be easily modified). Note that component `summary(fit)$alias` (see `?alias`) might be useful.

This seems to relate your other question: [Replace lm coefficients in [r]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417680/replace-lm-coefficients-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to include a column with all `NA` values. It does strange things to `model.matrix`

```
 x1 <- 1:5
 x2 <- rep(NA,5)

 model.matrix(~x1+x2) 
     (Intercept) x1 x2TRUE
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$x2
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

So your alternative is to programatically create the model formula based on the data.

Something like...

```
make_formula <- function(variables, data, response = 'y'){
   if(missing(data)){stop('data not specified')}
   using <-  Filter(variables,f= function(i) !all(is.na(data[[i]])))

   deparse(reformulate(using, response))
 }

 variables <- c('x1','x2','x3')

make_formula(variables, data =df)

[1] "y ~ x1 + x2"
```

I've used `deparse` to return a character string so that there is no `environment` issues from creating the formula within the function. `lm` can happily take a character string which is a valid formula.

Comment: +1 Very nice piece of code, as I'm currently designing some model building functions etc., this contained some interesting and possibly useful ideas (reformulate function was totally new to me).